# CUDA compiler (nvcc) macro

Tags: c++, cuda, macros, c-preprocessor, nvcc

Is there a #define compiler (nvcc) macro of CUDA which I can use? (Like _WIN32 for Windows and so on.)

I need this for header code that will be common between nvcc and VC++ compilers. I know I can go ahead and define my own and pass it as an argument to the nvcc compiler (-D), but it would be great if there is one already defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
__CUDACC__
```

I don't think it will be that trivial. Check the following thread

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=32369&st=0&p=179913&#entry179913

Comment: @AlejandroSazo: That is what it is supposed to print - it identifies whether code is being compiled through nvcc or another compiler.

Comment: The link is sadly expired, but the [doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-identification-macro) makes it seem _trivial_ enough; use `__NVCC__`

Answer (score 4):

I know it has been long time now, but you might also find  `__CUDA_ARCH__` useful.