# CUDA compiler macro to use on host code

Tags: c, linux, cuda

Is there a CUDA macro that may be used on host code to print which version of nvcc I am using? I know that nvcc -V should be enough by typing it on a terminal (linux) or in a harder way make the syscall with that line inside the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518995/cuda-compiler-nvcc-macro?rq=1 This was not helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See [the NVCC docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-identification-macro).

You *can* check the CUDA runtime or driver version at run time [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730706/749748).

Comment: The function cudaRuntimeGetVersion() is what I am looking for. The question should have been how to get the compiler that I am using while running a cuda program. Thanks for your references.

Comment: Great, thanks for accepting. `cudaRuntimeGetVersion()` gives you the version of the CUDA Runtime Library, *not* the version of the compiler.

Comment: Then I will have to do a backtracking of my concepts before ask what I said I should haha.